# Login.html not being called

Tags: javascript, python, html, ubuntu-server, bootstrap-5

I am working on a webserver at my job. My login page is not responding/redirecting me to the main page, and not accepting the username or password. Granted, this code was previously made by my Supervisor and handed to me to expand it. This is my only recurring issue. I am using Python, JavaScript and HTML with Bootstrap and this is running on an Ubuntu 20.04 server. The error it gives me is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SkriAdmin.py", line 788, in <module>
    httpServer.listen(port=tornado.options.options.port, address=tornado.options.options.host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 161, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

MainHandler

```
# Landing page/ Main Page
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    async def get(self):
        config = await self.readConfig()
        self.render("/index.html",config=config)
```

LoginHandler

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    async def get(self):
        self.render(r"/login.html")

    async def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # userAuth = await auth_os_user(user=self.get_argument('user'), password=self.get_argument('password'))
        # if userAuth == True:
        self.set_secure_cookie('skriadmin', self.get_argument('user'))
        self.redirect("/index.html")
        # else:
        #     self.redirect("/login")
```

Error appears on line 788 (Admin = SkriAdmin())

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
    asyncIO = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tornado.options.define("port", default=80, help="Run on the given port", type=int)
    tornado.options.define("host", default='0.0.0.0', help="Bind/listen on address", type=str)
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    try:
        logging.info("Initializing Admin")
        Admin = SkriAdmin()
        httpServer = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Admin)
        httpServer.listen(port=tornado.options.options.port, address=tornado.options.options.host)
        asyncIO.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.warning("Program halted")
        asyncIO.run_until_complete(asyncIO.shutdown_asyncgens())
        asyncIO.close()
        os._exit(0)
```

login.html

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="{{static_url('static/img/SkytecLogo144.png')}}">
        <h1>Rinet Admin</h1>
        <h2>Login</h2>
    </div>
    
    <form class="row g-3" action="/login" method="POST">
        {% module xsrf_form_html() %}
        <fieldset style="text-align: center;">
        <div>
          <input id="user" class="form-control" type="text" name="user" aria-placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-auto">
          <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" name="password" aria-placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
        </fieldset>

      </form>
```

I have tried changing the login handlers calling to the login page. This as far only takes my to the error mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

The error lies here `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

You are running your application on existing port.

Look at the default values here: 0.0.0.0:80 - 0.0.0.0 binds to all your avaliable networks.

```
tornado.options.define("port", default=80, help="Run on the given port", type=int)
tornado.options.define("host", default='0.0.0.0', help="Bind/listen on address", type=str)
```

Try define your port to 3000. 80 Is used by HTTP by default and if you are running f.e apache on port 80 (XAMPP etc...) it will not work.

Comment: Tried it, ran it but keeps giving me:            

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SkriAdmin.py", line 788, in <module>
    httpServer.listen(port=tornado.options.options.port, address=tornado.options.options.host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
    sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 161, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, it does not let me enter so it can be read more clearly

Comment: It is same error, did you realy updated your port? try log it before you ran application. It should work. Make sure you are not running app twice accidentaly. I never used tornado  in python, same behaviour/error display in nodeJS server if you are trying to open already existing port.

Comment: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html Here is an article which will helps you more with issue

Comment: Thank you, my login page is not loading, as it cannot connect to the website. I thank you for the tips and link..